# what is the best IDE i can use for deep learning?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, spyder

We are trying to train an LSTM under anaconda (spyder) from a dataset of size 333113kb. (3628801 rows * 31columns) The data is stored in a .csv file and is imported using the pandas library. The execution is too slow and somtimes spyder crashes.

NB : we are using an Intel Core (TM) i5-8300H CPU 2.3 GHz with 8Go of RAM.

Comment: Please give more information about problem. We can not understand what you mean about "train does not start".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not directly an IDE but I like to use Visual Studio Code because it's an excellent way to go even for machine learning and data science.

- it works on any OS
- supports many Technologies besides Python, C#, JS etc.
- open source and lightweight
- VS Code is integrated with PyLint
- You can perform unit testing on your machine learning models easily

for me VS Code makes working with SQL, .NET, Node.js and many other Tools a lot easier. It's a great code editor that supports you with operations like debugging, task running, version control and many other things that a full featured IDE can also do.

Answer (score -1):

Is this like university-wise project or commercial? You could try Google Colab.

Comment: HI, yes it is for my university project?